# Обрезать текст если он больше 439 символов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы текст обрезался если он больше 439 символов и при наводе появлялся скролл. Установить фиксированную высоту не получится, так как адаптив и высота постоянно меняется и выходит уже не 439 символов. Вот что у меня получилось, но он не обрезается

```js
function reviews() {
        const reviewsText = document.querySelectorAll('.reviews__text');
    

        reviewsText.forEach(item  => {
            item.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
                if (e.target.innerHTML.length >= 439) {
                    e.target.style.overflow = 'scroll';
                }
            });

            item.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
                e.target.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            });
        });
    }

    reviews();
```

```css
.reviews__text {
    font-family: 'Futura PT Light';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 180%;
    color: #131313;
    max-width: 480px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
                        <p class="reviews__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, velLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel</p>
```

Comment: Что у всех за дуращкая привычка что-то обрезать по количество символов? Символы бывают разные - может быть "ШШШШШШШШ", а может быть "iiiiiiii", но в обоих случаях это 8 символов. И моноширенного шрифта в воспросе явно нет.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, рубить текст не по точному количеству знаков, а по количеству строк на экране, используя свойство [line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp)

```js
function reviews() {
  const reviewsText = document.querySelectorAll('.reviews__text');
  reviewsText.forEach(item => {
    item.style.height = item.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });
}

reviews();
```

```css
.reviews__text {
  font-family: 'Futura PT Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 180%;
  color: #131313;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.reviews__text:hover {
  -webkit-line-clamp: initial;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<p class="reviews__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, velLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis,
  lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus magna fringilla urna, porttitor rhoncus
  dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo, vel</p>
```

Comment: Но работает он только в хромиумах...

Comment: @Qwertiy для некритичных фишек глобальная поддержка 97% — это ок, грех желать большего )

Comment: Ого, заглянул на caniuse - оказывается, в FF тоже реализовали поддержку о_О Значит я неправ, работает на всём современном.